# Azure SQL Pricing

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a small question about azure SQL.

I have a free website (website preview) on azure, and would like to add a database for it.

I have tried the free mysql from cleardb, but the connection limit made it too difficult to use.

Now I want to add a azure sql database, but I can't figure out the pricing for it.

A 100mb database costs $5 per month. But is that all, or will there come additional charges for traffic, calculations and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All inbound data sent to Windows Azure is free. Outbound data is charged based on the total amount of data moving out of the Windows Azure datacenters via the Internet in a given billing cycle. Data transfers between Windows Azure services located within the same datacenter are not subject to any charge. The first 5 GB of outbound data transfers per billing month are also free.

In your case, it's $5 a month, it's highly unlikely you'll use anywhere near the 5GB free bandwidth limit.